# What characters can come out of encodeURIComponent()?

Tags: javascript, regex, encodeuricomponent

Since javascript's `encodeURIComponent()` encodes everything except

```
(alphabetic)
(decimal digits)
-
_
.
!
~
*
'
(
)
```

and encodes these into strings of the format `%{digits}`

Is it true to say that `encodeURIComponent` always returns some combination of

```
- _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) %
```

plus digits and alphabetic characters, or are there any that I have missed?

Additionally, is it fair to say that any string matched here:

```
/[^\_\-\.\!\~\*\'\(\)\d\w\%]/ig.test(string)
```

Has therefore definitely not had `encodeURIComponent` applied to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [**the docs**](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

```
encodeURIComponent escapes all characters except the following
alphabetic, decimal digits, - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )
```

So I would say you are correct.